# Unable to get calculation to declare

Tags: python

I have tried different variables, and even wrote it in words only and Im not sure what I keep missing that seems to not click in my mind.

```
#Description of program
print( "This program will assist home owners calculate measure of water for in-ground swimming pool.")
# prompt homeowner to input press enter 7 times
print = input("Please Press Enter 7 times")
print = (input("Welcome! Let’s get right to it!"))
print = (input("  ☆ * . ☆"))
print = (input("*    . ∧＿∧ ∩ * ☆"))
print = (input("* ☆ ( ・∀・)/ ."))
print = (input("  . ⊂⠀⠀⠀⠀ノ* ☆"))
print = (input(" ☆ * (つ ノ .☆"))
print = (input("       (ノ"))
# Prompt three variables, inputs as a decimal (int)
height = float(input("Enter the tank height (ft): "))
width = float(input("Enter the tank width (ft): "))
depth = float(input("Enter the tank depth (ft): "))

#prompt total liters
exec
total = float(height) * float(width) * float(depth) / 100000

#total
print = (total)
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you have that line containing `exec`?  What are you expecting that to do?

Comment: Don't use `print` as a variable name. Also, use `print(total)` rather than `print = (total)` when you want to actually print the total.

Comment: Try to run your program twice in a row, without restarting the runtime (just copy-paste your code twice) and see what happens. Can you guess why is this happening?

Comment: I had asked for some help in person from someone that used to code and told me to try exce.. Thank you to all of you for the help and advice I will try it out and update yah on the status

Comment: wk2.py", line 29, in <module>
    print (total)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

after I run it twice and  fixing it to print(total)

Comment: NEVERMIND I JUST REMOVED THE TOP PART UP TP THE THREE VARIABLES AND IT WORKED YAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAYYY!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve by dividing it by 100000
and why are you using print as a variable name? If you want to print the capacity of the underground storage tank with the graphics getting displayed alongside, you could go with the following approach.

```
print( "This program will assist home owners calculate measure of water for in-ground swimming pool.")
# prompt homeowner to input press enter 7 times


print('''Welcome! Let’s get right to it!
☆ * . ☆
*    . ∧＿∧ ∩ * ☆
* ☆ ( ・∀・)/ .
  . ⊂⠀⠀⠀⠀ノ* ☆
 ☆ * (つ ノ .☆
       (ノ
''')
height = float(input("Enter the tank height (ft): "))
width = float(input("Enter the tank width (ft): "))
depth = float(input("Enter the tank depth (ft): "))

#There's no need to use float as it was already convered to float while getting the input.
total = (height * width * depth) * 28.317
total_two = (height * width * depth) / 100000

#Multiplying the total with 28.317 to convert to litre
# if you want to display the result by dividing it by 100000 use total_two
      
#total
print(total)
#print(total_two)
```

Just uncomment the print(total_two) if you want to display the result by dividing them by 100000 and remove print(total)

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code to remove all redundant parenthesis and it's working.

```
# Description of program
print("This program will assist home owners calculate measure of water for in-ground swimming pool.")
# prompt homeowner to input press enter 7 times

print("Welcome! Let’s get right to it!")
print("  ☆ * . ☆")
print("*    . ∧＿∧ ∩ * ☆")
print("* ☆ ( ・∀・)/ .")
print("  . ⊂⠀⠀⠀⠀ノ* ☆")
print(" ☆ * (つ ノ .☆")
print("       (ノ")
# Prompt three variables, inputs as a decimal (int)
height = float(input("Enter the tank height (ft): "))
width = float(input("Enter the tank width (ft): "))
depth = float(input("Enter the tank depth (ft): "))

# prompt total liters
exec
total = float(height) * float(width) * float(depth) / 100000
total = float(total)

print(total)
```

Comment: Thank you Dennis One day ill look back on my beginner python and laugh how simple the fixes are that I could not see